# Reading Blob Into Pyspark

Tags: azure-databricks

I'm trying to read in a series of json files stored in an azure blob into spark using the databricks notebook. I set the conf() with my account and key but it always returns the error

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The String is not a valid Base64-encoded string.
```

I've followed along with the information provided here:

https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/data-import/azure-blob-store.html

and here:

https://luminousmen.com/post/azure-blob-storage-with-pyspark

I can pull the data just fine using the azure sdk for python

```
storage_account_name = "name"
storage_account_access_key = "key"

spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
  storage_account_access_key)

file_location = "wasbs://loc/locationpath"
file_type = "json"

df = spark.read.format(file_type).option("inferSchema", "true").load(file_location)
```

Should return a dataframe of the json file

Comment: Maybe double check the account key? The error seems like it may not have the entire key since it's saying it isn't a valid base64 string.

Comment: @Jon. This this helped me solve the issue. The problem was with an incorrect account key for me which showed up as the error mentioned in the question

Comment: @stormfield Glad it helped! :)